# Display text on left and right side of webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to divide the web page into two columns and display text. My html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first styled page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">

    <script>

    function showAlert() {
     var myString = "I should be printed on left side";
              alert("onclick Event detected! " + this.innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("two").innerHTML = myString;
        }


    window.onload = function mydisplayArray() {
          var array = ['abc','xyz','mno']; 

    for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            var span = document.createElement('span');
            span.innerHTML = array[i];
            span.onclick = showAlert; 
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            //var div = document.getElementById('one'); // This interchanges the columns and displayes array elements in single line without any space, so this doesn't works
            div.appendChild(span);
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            }
    }

    </script>
   </head>

  <body>
      <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
        <h1>Main Title of Web Page</h1>
         Here I am trying to split the webpage into two columns and display text.
      </div>
     <div id="one">
     </div>
     <div id="two">
          <b>This is test one<br>
          <b>This is test two<br>
          </b>
     </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

My css file is:

```
  #container {
     width:100%;
     height:200px;
     }

  #header {
    margin-bottom:0;
    background-color:red;
   }

 #one {
    width:40%;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:yellow;
   }

#two {
   width:60%;
   height:200px;
   float:left;
   background-color:cyan;
   }
```

Now, my problem is that I am not able to display the array elements on the right side of the page, means I want to display it within the `div` id `one`. If I try to do so (see my html file `var div`), then the columns gets interchanged and the array elements are shown in single line with out any space between them. So, obviously that's not the correct way to do it. How can I display the array elements within the `div` id `one`?

Currently, my array elements are getting displayed below the `div` id `one`, means below the `yellow` color. I want it to be displayed within the `yellow` color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, very simple error, see [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/t7dfb/)

1. Edit your js
   `//document.body.appendChild(div); YOU SHOULD COMMENT THIS OUT`
2. Add this to css
   `#one > span {display:block;}`

You are appending the div to the whole body that's why it breaks out of the container div.